# UIScrollView->DrawingView delaysContentTouches NO

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, drawing

Here's one for you guys.
I have a drawing view as a subview of UIScrollView. I would like to be able to draw freely and zoom/scroll using 2 fingers. I found that if delaysContentTouches is YES (default), if you flick your finger or the pencil, you do not receive touchesMoved: as expected.

If delaysContentTouches is NO, then you receive all events. However, if you then try and use 2 fingers to scroll or zoom, you receive touch events which then draw on the drawing view, which you ideally don't want, because you are zooming or scrolling. With delaysContentTouches NO, the drawing view gets the event right away and then the UIScrollView gets the event later which means AFAIK I have no way to know if the touches should be ignored in the drawing subview. 
Any ideas? Thanks!